# Laravel asset() incorrect link

Tags: laravel

I am using "public" fiilesystem driver and I store files at:

`PROJECT_ROOT/storage/app/public/message_files`

But I can also access them from here (since I've created a symlink):

`PROJECT_ROOT/public/storage/message_files`

Then I try to get a link to the file using asset() helper and it receives a path like this one:

`message_files/gwYRplTEyX9O3Z1sOYXxk2C3ZfLVSiIZF93nZbjz.txt`

and returns:

`http://localhost/message_files/gwYRplTEyX9O3Z1sOYXxk2C3ZfLVSiIZF93nZbjz.txt`

As you can see, there's no "storage" directory in the URL, so the link is incorrect. My question is: can we set any settings so that the "storage" directory isn't omitted?

Here is my filesystems.config:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the default filesystem disk that should be used
    | by the framework. The "local" disk, as well as a variety of cloud
    | based disks are available to your application. Just store away!
    |
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'public'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cloud Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Many applications store files both locally and in the cloud. For this
    | reason, you may specify a default "cloud" driver here. This driver
    | will be bound as the Cloud disk implementation in the container.
    |
    */

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure as many filesystem "disks" as you wish, and you
    | may even configure multiple disks of the same driver. Defaults have
    | been setup for each driver as an example of the required options.
    |
    | Supported Drivers: "local", "ftp", "s3", "rackspace"
    |
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
            'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's normal that `asset()` points to the public root, and changing this would probably have side effects.

You may be looking for [`Storage::url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to access your storage with asset. you have to run the command

`php artisan storage:link` then you can add storage in asset like `asset(storage/your/path)`

I hope this helps

Comment: I've already created a link, but the thing is I don't want to manually add "storage" to every single path used by asset() helper, I want to add it globally for all links if you know what I mean.

Comment: @you need to append app in your path

Comment: Can you show me an example? I am not really sure I know what you mean.